# Python Execute() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.x, execute

I am trying to insert into the SQLite DataBase values with this code:

```
con.Execute('''UPDATE tblPlayers SET p_Level = ? WHERE p_Username= ? ''', (PlayerLevel,PlayerUsername))
```

this is the Execute function:

```
def Execute(self,SQL):
    self.__connection.execute(SQL)
    self.__connection.comit()
```

and i am getting this error:

> con.Execute('''UPDATE tblPlayers SET p_Level = ? WHERE p_Username= ?
>   ''', (PlayerLevel,PlayerUsername)) TypeError: Execute() takes exactly
>   2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: what? .... you need `con.execute` case matters ... I was not aware of the Execute function at all ... is con not a normal sqlite3 db_cursor?

Comment: i created my own DB class based on sqlite to make it easier to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Execute()` method takes only two arguments, `self` and `SQL`. The `self` argument is supplied by Python to bound methods, so there is only room for the `SQL` argument:

```
def Execute(self,SQL):
```

but you called the bound method with an additional argument, not just the one `SQL` argument:

```
con.Execute('''UPDATE tblPlayers SET p_Level = ? WHERE p_Username= ? ''',
            (PlayerLevel,PlayerUsername))
```

The tuple value passed in, together with the auto-inserted `self` argument and the `SQL` argument makes *three*.

If you want to support SQL parameters, you'll need to accept those parameters:

```
def Execute(self, SQL, params=()):
    self.__connection.execute(SQL, params)
    self.__connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line says you are inputting two arguments:

```
con.Execute('''UPDATE tblPlayers SET p_Level = ? WHERE p_Username= ? ''', (PlayerLevel,PlayerUsername))
```

Add those 2 arguments to the *implicit* `self` argument that's passed automatically with the instance, you now have 3 arguments.

Either keep to 1 argument when calling it or modify the definition of `Execute` to accomodate 1 more argument.