# Load csv into hana database using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hana

I'm using `pyhdb` to connect to Hana database and I'm reading a csv using `pandas`. When I try to insert row by row after iterating through the dataframe I get an error. How to insert all rows from a csv into HANA database?

**Code:**

```
import pyhdb
import csv
import pandas as pd

connection = pyhdb.connect(
    host="xxx.xx.xx.xx",
    port=26444,
    user="user",
    password="pass"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cols = ['VBELN','MATNR','PODREL','LFIMG']
df = pd.read_csv("D:\LIPS.csv",usecols=cols,dtype=str)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.LIPS (VBELN, MATNR, LFIMG, PODREL ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
                   row['VBELN'],row['MATNR'],row['LFIMG'],row['PODREL'])
```

> TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were
>   given

Comment: Just like the error message states, the `execute()` function can take only 2 or 3 parameters. See the [source](https://github.com/SAP/PyHDB/blob/master/pyhdb/cursor.py#L233).

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220691/python-execute-takes-exactly-2-arguments-3-given

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
(row['VBELN'],row['MATNR'],row['LFIMG'],row['PODREL'])
```

instead of

```
row['VBELN'],row['MATNR'],row['LFIMG'],row['PODREL']
```

It should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in execute method should be passed as a tuple not comma separated.

Also I am no expert but I think it would be better to mark arguments as *%s* either than 
*?*

Which might be useful in the next step: remember to cursor.commit() the changes you will do to your database.